# Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time- debugging enabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, visual-studio-code, jit

I have a .NET Web project developed on VisualStudio Code and I'm trying to update the IIS Application with the new changes but, when I start the IIS again, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled win32 exception ocurred in w3wp.exe [4384].
Just-InTime debugging this exception failed with the following error:
No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time
```

Notice that I'm getting my new .DLL and uploading this one to another machine (where the IIS is working).

To compile my project I used:

```
dotnet build
dotnet publish
```

I didn't have any kind of .config

Someone have any idea how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: try to set the iis application pool to enable 32 bit to true or Debug ==> Options ==> Search for iis ==> enable using of 64bit Version of IIS Express. also, try to Disable the Just-In-Time Debugger [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-in-time-debugging-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)